# Display Issues CSS

Tags: html, css

Below is a link to a JSFiddle. I am having trouble as there is meant to be an image with text at the very start of the `site-wrap` div named `background-image` with `text` being inside that div.

If I add `line-height` to the `text` div, the height is adjusted to suit that, however I am just looking to add a full page height and width to the div and center the text afterwards.

https://jsfiddle.net/zqh0fb2o/1/

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to have the image displayed so that it would make a complete, static banner, in-between the menu hyperlinks? Would it scrolls with the rest of the page like the menus do? Assuming yes, it would be much more sensible to restructure the HTML so that the div came between `menu-1-left` and `menu-1-right`. Also, assuming the banner purely says 'Contact Us', it might be simpler to actually draw the text into the image itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Obsidian. I am actually looking for it to be more of a "header" for the page as it will NOT be static/fixed. Instead it will scroll with the content of the page in `site-wrap`

Oh, and the blank between the menu items is where the logo is meant to be.

Comment: I'm still not understanding the problem fully, sorry. So the problem is that you need to ensure that the 'Contact Us' text remains vertically-centered depending on the size of the image? One way to do that would be to apply `display: table` to `background-image`, and both `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` to `text`. Also remove both `height` and `line-height` from `text`. That would assure that the text is always vertically centered, though note that the `background-image` would need offsetting from the `top-bar` due to the current HTML structure.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but unfortunately it has not worked for me.

If you take another one of my projects for example, (http://www.splicepro.com.au/) the slideshow is displayed at 100% of the page height and width. All that I want to do in the new project is add text in the center of the image and make the image 100% height and width.

Comment: Please give your question a meaningful title describing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The way you worded your question is a bit confusing but I believe you are looking for:

```
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
```

**vw** is viewport width and **vh** is viewport height.

Comment: I've been stuck with this for a few days now and didn't even THINK to use the viewport values. Genius!